# Проблема при скролинге с загрузкой фотографий в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, изображения, recyclerview, android-imageview

У меня есть RecyclerView, при скроллинге экрана на экране сначала отображаются фотографии верхнего экрана, а только потом подгружаются правильные фотографии. Не знаю, как решить эту проблему.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final Activity context;

    private final ArrayList<Folder> FOLDERS;
    View view;

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.wtf("TAG","Folders size: "+ FOLDERS.size());
        return FOLDERS.size();
    }

    public int getPosition(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //bitmap optimisation
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

    public void loadBitmap(String path, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        task.execute(path);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public TextView title;
        ImageView image1;
        ImageView image2;
        ImageView image3;
        ImageView image4;
        ImageView image5;
        TextView  slides;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
            image1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
            image2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
            image3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon3);
            image4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon4);
            image5 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon5);
            slides = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }
    }
    public MyAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Folder> FOLDERS) {
        this.context = context;
        this.FOLDERS = FOLDERS;
        getItemCount();
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Folder folder = FOLDERS.get(position);
        ArrayList<String> imgs = folder.getPicturelist();
        holder.title.setText(folder.getName());
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            options.inSampleSize = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        loadBitmap(imgs.get(i), holder.image1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        loadBitmap(imgs.get(i), holder.image2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        loadBitmap(imgs.get(i), holder.image3);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        loadBitmap(imgs.get(i), holder.image4);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        loadBitmap(imgs.get(i), holder.image5);
                        break;
                }
            }

            holder.slides.setText("Количество слайдов: " + imgs.size());
            view.setTag(holder);
    }
}
```

Код AsyncTask

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> viewHolderWeakReference;
    private String data;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        viewHolderWeakReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Async task works in background");
        data = String.valueOf(params[0]);
        Log.wtf("Params: ", params[0]);
        final Bitmap bitmap =decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data, 30, 30);
        addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.i("onPostExecute", "works!");
        if (viewHolderWeakReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView= viewHolderWeakReference.get();
            if (imageView != null){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
    public  void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            FirstscreenActivity.mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }
    public  Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return FirstscreenActivity.mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }
}
```

Так же привожу код onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front);
        list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        getFromSdcardFolders();
        list.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, FOLDERS);
        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        mMemoryCache
                = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Можно чуточку поподробнее описать суть проблемы? и какой нужен результат

Comment: @Chaynik   Проблема уже решилась, но собственно до этого в  RecyclerView происходил хаос https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HA3CcmfuM6w&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если не хочешь видеть результаты предыдущего, то в `onBindViewHolder` в холдер перед загрузкой нового изображения положи `null`.

```
holder.image1.setImageBitmap(null)
// и т.д.
```

Все дело в том, что `RecyclerView` переиспользует предыдущие `view` если их стало не видно, а загрузка изображений у вас асинхронная, и следовательно успевает отобразиться старое изображение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло!

Comment: Если скролить медленно, то все работает хорошо, но если проскролить быстро в самый низ, то все равно загружаются фотографии с предыдущего экрана.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ButSUAdtQiM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Потому что предыдущий таск на эту картинку еще не отработал а ты навешиваешь еще один. Сохрани Map<Image,BitmapWorkerTask> с информацией о таске и картинке, и когда на картинку создаешь новый таск отменяй предыдущий. Просто у тебя сразу 2 таска на один ImageView работает.